# How to convert each digit in an int to hex

Tags: python

I want to convert an integer variable to hex value digit wisely. That means, for 499, I need an output of "/x04/x09/x09". Somebody please help.

Comment: Convert it to a string and then subtract 48 from each character. That works because the string is encoded in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string formatting functions:

```
n = 499
print("".join("\\x{0:02x}".format(int(i)) for i in str(n)))
```

prints

```
\x04\x09\x09
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
'/'.join(map(hex,map(int,str(input_number))))
```

This takes the number, turns it into a string, turns this into an int list, applies hex, then joins everything together by a slash.

This isn't terribly pythonic, but it gets the job done (in 1 line).